# Javascript multiplication when add row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my code, when I add the javascript multiplication not running, but at first row just fine. I think the problem id must be unique and i change to name, but still not work.

You can try mycode below.

```js
function multiplyBy() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  document.getElementById("output").value = num1 * num2;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addCF").click(function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<tr><td>1</td><td><input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" onkeyup="calc()" value="" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control" id="input2" onkeyup="calc()" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control" name="sub_total[]" value="" id="output" type="text"></td><td><button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button></td></tr>');
  });
  $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table class='table table-bordered' id='customFields'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style='width:35px;'>#</th>
      <th style='width:210px;'>Nama Barang</th>
      <th style='width:120px;'>Harga</th>
      <th style='width:75px;'>Qty</th>
      <th style='width:125px;'>Sub Total</th>
      <th style='width:40px;'></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" id="cariBrg" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" onkeyup="multiplyBy()" value="" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" id="input2" onkeyup="multiplyBy()" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" name="sub_total[]" id="output" onkeyup="multiplyBy()" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id='addCF' class='btn btn-default pull-left'><i class='fa fa-plus fa-fw'></i> Baris Baru (F7)</button>
```

Comment: Well... `onkeyup="calc()"`? What's that supposed to mean? Remove it, because there is no `calc` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same id multiple times and it gives wrong behavior with jquery/javascript. I have added some classes into each text boxes and replaced `mutiplyby` function with on `keyup` jquery function.

Try this with your page and see it gives you your desired output.

```js
$(document).on('keyup','.input',function(){
    var num1 = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('.input:first').val();
    var num2 = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('.input:last').val();
    $(this).parents('tr:first').find('.sub-total').val(num1 * num2);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addCF").click(function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<tr><td>1</td><td><input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control input input1" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" onkeyup="multiplyBy(this)" value="" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control input input2" id="input2" onkeyup="multiplyBy()" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control sub-total" name="sub_total[]" value="" id="output" type="text"></td><td><button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button></td></tr>');
  });
  $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table class='table table-bordered' id='customFields'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style='width:35px;'>#</th>
      <th style='width:210px;'>Nama Barang</th>
      <th style='width:120px;'>Harga</th>
      <th style='width:75px;'>Qty</th>
      <th style='width:125px;'>Sub Total</th>
      <th style='width:40px;'></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" id="cariBrg" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control input" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" onkeyup="multiplyBy()" value="" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control input" id="input2" onkeyup="multiplyBy()" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control sub-total" name="sub_total[]" id="output" onkeyup="multiplyBy()" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id='addCF' class='btn btn-default pull-left'><i class='fa fa-plus fa-fw'></i> Baris Baru (F7)</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of `id` attributes must be unique across the whole document. Each time you do the calculation you are adding another element with the id `output`. The DOM doesn't know which one you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem id must be unique and i change to name

Yes that's it, the `id` should be unique in the same document, instead you don't need `id`'s here it will be better to use common classes :

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control calculation" name="harga_satuan[]" value="" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control calculation" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control output" name="sub_total[]" id="" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**NOTE :** No need for inline-events better to attach your event in the JS code, Check my suggestion using `input` event that is more efficient than `keyup` when you track the user input's.

I've added also an index to enumerate the rows...

Hope this helps.

**Working Snippet :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 2;
  
  $("#addCF").click(function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<tr><td>'+index+'</td><td><input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control calculation" name="harga_satuan[]" value="" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control calculation" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control output" name="sub_total[]" value="" type="text"></td><td><button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="color:red;"></i></button></td></tr>');

    index++;
  });
  
  $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
  
  $("table").on('input', '.calc', function(){
     var parent_row = $(this).closest('tr');
     
     var num1 = parent_row.find('[name="harga_satuan[]"]').val();
     var num2 = parent_row.find('[name="jumlah_beli[]"]').val();
     
     parent_row.find('.output').val(num1*num2);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class='table table-bordered' id='customFields'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style='width:35px;'>#</th>
      <th style='width:210px;'>Nama Barang</th>
      <th style='width:120px;'>Harga</th>
      <th style='width:75px;'>Qty</th>
      <th style='width:125px;'>Sub Total</th>
      <th style='width:40px;'></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text">
      </td>
      <td><input class="form-control calc" name="harga_satuan[]" value="" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control calc" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control output" name="sub_total[]" id="" type="text"></td>
      <td><button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id='addCF' class='btn btn-default pull-left'><i class='fa fa-plus fa-fw'></i> Baris Baru (F7)</button>
```